# Run JAVA 8 jar on windows without command prompt

Tags: java, windows, jar, click, double

This is a simple Hello World test application.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

It was exported as "Runnable JAR File" in Eclipse.
[image]

Opening it using `java -jar hello.jar` on Command Prompt works.

However when trying to open it using double click, nothing happens.

Note 1 : Java Platform is the default program associated with this type.

[image]

Note 2 : `java -version`

> java version "1.8.0_60"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build1.8.0_60-b27)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

**The problem** Double click does not execute a command line JAVA 8 jar file.
How can i solve it?

Comment: Stackoverflow answers **that i have found** do not address the exact problem or are outdated.

Comment: You'd have to attach a console to your program. If you start it from your cmd prompt directly you'll use this prompt instance to run it on. Your jar on the other hand has no such cmd prompt instance.

Comment: I think u need to create a bat/exe file which actually execute the `java -jar hello.jar` command.

Comment: @BenWin Can you further explain?

Comment: @UUIIUI I thought about doing this but, it seems to be too much of a hassle to do a simple execute task. I will probably resort to this if i can't find any other solutions.

Comment: @naaz, can you mark whichever answer solved your issue as the accepted answer please.

Comment: @AndyDavies Actually, all of them were useful. I couldn't choose one over the others.

Comment: It's still best to mark the one you found most helpful as the accepted answer so that other people reading the question can get to an answer quicker.

Answer (score 3):

If you doubleclick a `*.jar` it is actually started with `javaw -jar Hello.jar`. The difference between `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` is that with `javaw` there is no associated console window. As your test application do not show any GUI element, it looks like as it would not be executed.

Depending what you want to achieve you either create a script to run your application or you make some graphical interface.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the JAR from File Explorer, there's no shell for it to write the text output to. When you run it from the command line, it's already wrapped in a shell so the `System.out` stream is already set to the shell's output stream and so print statements are visible.

The simplest *practical* solution would be to create a batch file that performs the `java -jar hello.jar` command which would launch a command window when you open it in File Explorer.

Another solution would be to launch a `cmd.exe` context from within your Java application using `Runtime.exec()` and set your output stream to the same as the process object it returns.

The most elegant solution, but one which requires a bit more background work, would be to instantiate a simple GUI consisting of a *JFrame* and a *JTextArea* within a *JScrollPane*, then you would append your output to the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar may be opening with javaw.exe. You can verify that by executing command

```
ftype | find "jarfile"
```

If its showing  as `javaw.exe`

```
ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

change it to `java.exe`

```
ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: Changing it to 'java.exe' will make a Command Prompt launch every time a jar file is executed even if it was a GUI application.

However for this command to work, you have to start Command Prompt as Administrator.